# Binding a Textbox in KNockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, textbox

I am new to knockout.I would like to bind a textbox to a viewmodel.I have the following code,but its not working.Could someone point me in the right direction.

I am trying to post the data from my view model to a controller,but the values are null,even though I have entered values into the textboxes

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="ProviderForm" method="post">
        <div class=" form-group">
            <label for="Provider" class="control-label col-sm-2">PROVIDER :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul id="demolist" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Doctor</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="datebox" data-bind="value: ProviderType" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" form-group">
            <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" data-bind="value: FirstName" placeholder="Enter the First Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" data-bind="value: Lastname" placeholder="Enter the Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Certification" class="control-label col-sm-2">Certification :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul id="demolist2" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">M.D.</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">D.O.</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="datebox2" data-bind="value: Certification" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Specialization" class="control-label col-sm-2">Specialization :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul id="demolist3" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Family Practitioner</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Dentist</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Emergency Doctor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="datebox3" data-bind="value: Specialization" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SSN" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SSN</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSSN" data-bind="value: SSN" placeholder="Enter your SSN">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FacilityName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facility Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFacility" data-bind="textInput: FacilityName" placeholder="Enter your Facility">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ContactNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="inputContactNum" data-bind="value: ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter your Facility">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="EmailID" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" data-bind="value: ContactEmail" placeholder="Enter your Email ID">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions span7 text-center">
            <button type="submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md ">Save</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-md ">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My Script

```
            $("document").ready(function () {            
                $("#Submit").on("click",function(){     
                  var Provider = 
                    {
                        ProviderType: ko.observable(""),
                        FirstName: ko.observable(""),
                        Lastname: ko.observable(""),
                        Certification: ko.observable(""),
                        Specialization: ko.observable(""),
                        SSN: ko.observable(""),
                        ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
                        ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
                        FacilityName : ko.observable("")
                    }

                    ko.applyBindings(Provider);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/PatientRegister/Create",
                        data : Provider
                    });
                });
            });
```

In the controller,I am using this provider as a parameter.

```
    public ActionResult Create(Provider provider)
    {
      //.... 
    }
```

At present,the provider fields are null.I have also created a Provider Class with the same paramter names

```
public class Provider
    {
        public string ProviderType { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Certification { get; set; }
        public string Specialization { get; set; }
        public string SSN { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set;}
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect this code to work?

You need to make your `provider` object observable when your pageload,

```
 var Provider = 
                    {
                        ProviderType: ko.observable(""),
                        FirstName: ko.observable(""),
                        Lastname: ko.observable(""),
                        Certification: ko.observable(""),
                        Specialization: ko.observable(""),
                        SSN: ko.observable(""),
                        ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
                        ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
                        FacilityName : ko.observable("")
                    }

                    ko.applyBindings(Provider);
```

and on click of submit button post this object to your controller.

So how knockout cycle work is like, once you say `ko.applyBindings(Provider)` it will start observing your controls, and whenever you change any value in your control, knockout will automatically update associated property of your control.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdjp461j/)

Comment: I already am binding it to the provider.What am I missing here?How do I make the provider observable on pageload.

Comment: Thanks a lot,its working now.Although,the textboxes that are getting populated dynamically though the dropdown menu are still null i.e; the Provider type,Certification and Specialization.

Comment: so what do you mean by dynamically ?
so if it's getting loaded by some ajaxcalls after page load, then make sure you say, `ko.applyBindings(Provider)` once all the controls are rendered in your page, that means you must call ko.applybindings after your ajax calls,if possible post your entire javascript code.